# Access Log for VNC for KVM/libvirt/virt-manager

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

Is there a way to look at who makes a VNC connection to the host on the default port?

I could not find any documentation or questions on the web related to this.

Is there any log file that tracks those VNC connections or disconnections?